# Android Studio trying to export APK, giving me an error

Tags: export, apk

I'm trying to export my app to APK to upload it to Google Play, but it gives me the following error -

```
    Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file. Try supplying a main-dex list.
# methods: 76604 > 65536
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file. Try supplying a main-dex list.
# methods: 76604 > 65536, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

Hope you guys can help me out!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your app contains too much code to fit in a single dex file.

There are multiple ways to solve this problem:

- If you don't use proguard, do so now. That's the best way today to optimize your app in terms of size. Have a read how to do so here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code
- If you already use proguard and still can't fit everything in a single dex file, then look into enabling multidex. All the information here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Hope that helps!